# Rotate objects without loading a new map

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Guys,

I looked the last 2 days for a way to rotate objects in an existing world without loading a new map .

I use Ros Gazebo with Turtlebot..The turtlebot drive to several objects after he has complete his task I want.to rotate all objects that he can drive in an new ankle to them. I didn't find a good solution  maybe someone can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17583/rotate-objects-without-loading-a-new-map/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3848/baumboon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You have a few options:

1. Since you're using ROS, you can publish to `/gazebo/set_model_state`, [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_comm#SetModelPoseandTwistinSimulationviaTopics)'s a tutorial.
2. Or you could use Gazebo transport and publish a message to the `~/model/modify` topic
3. Finally, you can always write a world plugin which sets the pose of objects in the world. [Here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world_properties&cat=write_plugin)'s a tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3848/baumboon/) on 2017-10-24**:
Is there a way to rotate all Objects with one command? Or do i need to publish all states and positions of each Object?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-10-25**:
It depends on your model's kinematic structure, as mentioned on an answer to another question, I suggest you get familiar with Gazebo's model concepts before trying to control models ;)